# How to insert ISODate and ObjectId in couchbase

Tags: mongodb, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am migrating data from mongo to couchbase. My mongo documents contains ISODate and ObjectId as in the following sample document.

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58638a8d6a0b12b41ceec1dd"),
"lastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-12-28T12:13:12.069Z"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2016-12-28T09:49:00.985Z")
}
```

Couchbase is not accepting not ISODate and ObjectId. Inserts are failing
with the following error message.

```
ISODate is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example does not contain valid JSON, you should encode your values as JSON. The spec is here http://www.json.org/. For example, this is valid JSON:

```
{
  "_id": {"_type": "ObjectId", "_value": "58638a8d6a0b12b41ceec1dd"},
  "lastUpdated": {"_type": "ISODate", "_value": "2016-12-28T12:13:12.069Z"},
  "createdAt": {"_type": "ISODate", "_value": "2016-12-28T09:49:00.985Z"}
}
```

Comment: No, That is how mongo stores dates and objectids.

Comment: Mongo does not support JSON, they are using BSON. In Couchbase you should use JSON.